# cascading lists that won't delete on filter dependent values

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Is it possible to make cascading lists that won't delete on filter dependent values?

Parent cascading LOV don't allow this solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain (in detail, so it is obvious to anyone reading it what you mean)  "won't delete on filter dependent values".

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, it is the "Parent required" property which is supposed to be turned OFF.

[image]

---

If it doesn't help, then modify LoV query to "ignore" NULL values in parent item:

```
select ...
from ...
where (department = :P1_DEPARTMENT or :P1_DEPARTMENT is null)
```

Doing so, you'll either filter data on department, or - if it doesn't exist - you'll get *all rows*.